# remove quotation in array

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I have a string like this:-

```
$a = " [abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]";
```

I want to insert this string into an array.

```
$marker_tower_line = array(
    'type' => 'Feature',
    'properties' => array(          
        'marker-color' => '#f00',
        'marker-size' => 'small'
    ),
    'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'LineString',
        'coordinates' => array (
             $a 
        )
    )
);
```

The output coming is-

```
["[abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]"];
```

But I need-

```
[[abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]];
```

Comment: But it is a sting as you say, so it will be quoted? What do you need to do with the data exactly?

Comment: You need to parse the string and convert into the array you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The most Simplest answer (one-liner with simple php functions):-***

```
<?php
$a = " [abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]";

$b = array_chunk(explode(",",str_replace(array("[","]"),array("",""),trim($a))),2);

print_r($b);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/833862

***Or a bit more shorten (without `trim()`):-***

```
<?php
$a = " [abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]";

$b = array_chunk(explode(",",str_replace(array("[","]"," "),array("","",""),$a)),2);

print_r($b);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/833882

Comment: @prabha  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this,

```
$somearray=explode(",",$a);
```

then use $somearray for coordinates. The only catch is that you have to use this idea to implement in your logic.For example if $a is the string that you are making then make it like this,

```
$a = "[abc,hjhd].,[ccdc,cdc].,[csc,vdfv]";
```

and then use explode as

```
$somearray=explode(".,",$a);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. The function `make_my_array()` will work for any string encoded in your given format.

The make_my_array() function takes your string as parameter and iterates through every character to make your output array. It determines staring of a set by '[' character and determines separate set elements by ',' character and the ']' character determines end of a set.

```
function make_my_array($sa) {
    $s = "";
    $ans = array();

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($sa); $i++) {
        $t = array();
        if($sa[$i] == '[') {
            for($j=$i+1; $j<strlen($sa); $j++) {
                if($sa[$j] == ',') {
                    $t[] = $s;
                    $s = "";
                }
                else if($sa[$j] == ']') {
                    $t[] = $s;
                    $s = "";
                    $i = $j + 1;
                    $ans[] = $t;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    $s .= $sa[$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $ans;
}


$a = " [abc,hjhd],[ccdc,cdc],[csc,vdfv]";
$marker_tower_line = array(
    'type' => 'Feature',
    'properties' => array(          
        'marker-color' => '#f00',
        'marker-size' => 'small'
    ),
    'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'LineString',
        'coordinates' => make_my_array($a)
    )
);
```

Comment: it's a very lengthy code to do and understand too.Please add an explanation what you did